# one-dimensional array shapes (length,) vs. (length,1) vs. (length)

Tags: python, arrays, math, numpy

When I check the shape of an array using `numpy.shape()`, I sometimes get `(length,1)` and sometimes `(length,)`.  It looks like the difference is a column vs. row vector... but It doesn't seem like that changes anything about the array itself [except some functions complain when I pass an array with shape `(length,1)`].

What is the difference between these two?
Why isn't the shape just, `(length)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point is that say a vector can be seen either as

- a vector
- a matrix with only one column
- a 3 dimensional array where the 2nd and 3rd dimensions have length one
- ...

You can add dimensions using `[:, np.newaxis]` syntax or drop dimensions using `np.squeeze`:

```
>>> xs = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> xs.shape
(5,)
>>> xs[:, np.newaxis].shape  # a matrix with only one column
(5, 1)
>>> xs[np.newaxis, :].shape  # a matrix with only one row
(1, 5)
>>> xs[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis].shape  # a 3 dimensional array
(5, 1, 1)
>>> np.squeeze(xs[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]).shape
(5,)
```

Comment: Is it explicitly a 'column', and not a row?  (i.e. can it be seen as 'a matrix with one row'?)

Comment: @zhermes `xs[:, np.newaxis]` is one-column matrix, `xs[np.newaxis, :]` is one-row matrix

Answer (score 6):

In Python, `(length,)` is a tuple, with one 1 item.  `(length)` is just parenthesis around a number.

In `numpy`, an array can have any number of dimensions, 0, 1, 2, etc.  You are asking about the difference between 1 and 2 dimensional objects.  `(length,1)` is a 2 item tuple, giving you the dimensions of a 2d array.

If you are used to working with MATLAB, you might be confused by the fact that there, all arrays are 2 dimensional or larger.

Comment: what would be an example of zero dimension array ?

Comment: `np.array(1)`.  Shape is `()` and `ndim` is 0.

Answer (score 2):

The (length,) array is an array where each element is a number and there are length elements in the array. The (length, 1) array is an array which also has length elements, but each element itself is an array with a single element. For example, the following uses length=3.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array( [[1],[2],[3]] )
>>> a.shape
>>> (3, 1)
>>> b = np.array( [1,2,3] )
>>> b.shape
>>> (3,)
```

Answer (score 0):

A vector in Python is actually a **two**-dimensional array. It's just a coincidence that the number of rows is 1 (for row vectors), or the number of columns is 1 (for column vectors).

By contrast, a one-dimensional array is not a vector (neither a row vector nor a column vector). To understand this, think a concept in geometry, scalar. A scalar only has one attribute, which is numerical. By contrast, a vector has two attributes, number and direction. Fortunately, in linear algebra, vectors also have "directions", although only two possible directions - either horizontal or vertical (unlike infinite possible directions in geometry). A one-dimensional array only has numerical meaning - it doesn't show which direction this array is pointing to. This is why we need two-dimensional arrays to describe vectors.