# missing dimension in numpy array shape

Tags: python, numpy

what is the difference between the following two (why is the dimension missing in the first case):

```
zeros((3,)).shape
Out[67]: (3,)

zeros((3,1)).shape
Out[68]: (3, 1)
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737000) answers your question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `shape` of an array is a tuple of its dimensions. An array with one dimension has a shape of (n,). A two dimension array has a shape of (n,m) and a three dimension array has a shape of (n,m,k) and so on.

When you change from `(3,)` to `(3,1)` you are changing from 1 dimension to 2 dimension.

You can keep adding dimensions in this way (You can check the number of dimensions of an array using `.ndim`):

One dimension:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((2))
array([ 0.,  0.])
>>> a.shape
(2,)
>>> a.ndim
1
```

Two dimensions:

```
>>> b = np.zeros((2,2))
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
>>> b.shape
(2,2)
>>> b.ndim
2
```

Three dimensions:

```
>>> c = np.zeros((2,2,2))
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
>>> c.shape
(2,2,2)
>>> c.ndim
3
```

Four dimensions:

```
>>> d = np.zeros((2,2,2,2))
array([[[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]],


       [[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]]])
>>> d.shape
(2,2,2,2)
>>> d.ndim
4
```